# replace one character in a string using iterated values from a string array

Tags: java, android, string-concatenation

I want to replace all particular character from a string using iterated values from a string array.

```
  String Sample = " Select * from table A where Id = ? or Id = ?";

  String [] args = new String[]{"12","14"}
```

I want to replace '?' from sample string with values of args.
new string should look like

```
  Sample = " Select * from table A where Id = 12 or Id = 14";
```

can any one help me with some best string replace methods in java

Comment: It looks like you're trying to construct a SQL query. This is not how to do it, look up SQL injection (what you're trying to do would be vulnerable to it). Then look up prepared statements to find out how to do this properly.

Comment: Look into `String.replaceFirst` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: You could generate the statement in the first place like: "Select * from table A where Id = " + args[0] + " or Id = " + args[1];

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have a misguided approach. You have a string that looks like designed for a prepared statement, and the array is the parameter list for that prepared statement. Use it as such. Don't replace the values manually.

Using prepared statements is also the recommended way instead of formatting a string with parameters.
You get huge benefits such as protection from SQL injection, type validation, and performance.

Search for using prepared statements. You might need to change the parameter array to `Object[]` with the correct value types in it instead of strings as you have it now.

Comment: But what if you really do need to generate a custom statement to pull some information based on the id? For safety you could try parse int for that matter.

Comment: @janos you are right, but i m in a particular situation to do so.

Comment: If you HAVE to do it then do so VERY carefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String Sample = " Select * from table A where Id = ? or Id = ?";
    String[] sampleSplitted = Sample.split("");
    String [] args = new String[]{"12","14"};
    String result = "";

    int found = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < sampleSplitted.length; i++){
        String currentPart = sampleSplitted[i];

        if(currentPart.equals("?")){
            currentPart = args[found];
            found++;
        }
        result = result + currentPart;
    }
```

Result:

```
" Select * from table A where Id = 12 or Id = 14"
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: You're right about the SQL injection. I'm just answering with a iterated way